# Saving output of spark to csv in spark 1.6

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-1.6

**Spark 1.6**
**scala**

How to save output to csv file of spark 1.6.

i did something like this.

```
myCleanData.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).csv(path="file:///filepath")
```

but it throw error as

```
cannot resolve symbol csv
```

i tried like this even.

for dependency

```
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

val outputfile = "file:///D:/path/output"

    val myCleanData= sqlContext.sql("""SELECT
                                               col1,
                                               col1,
                                               col1
                                               FROM dataframe
                                               WHERE col1 LIKE "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
                                                  """ )



    myCleanData.write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save(outputfile)
```

But this give error as `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class`

Please help if it is possible with spark 1.6.

Comment: `csv` is only available with Spark 2+. For Spark 1.6, add the dependency for Databricks Spark CSV and then use `myCleanData.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")`

Comment: @philantrovert: will it be something like this. myCleanData.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").path(filepath), please suggest

Comment: @philantrovert: can we read parquet file using notepad++. please help

Comment: You can't. Parquet is not plain text.

Comment: @philantrovert: so is there any way to read parquet file.